# Why cant I see my object behind glass in eevee?

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine, glass

I can't see the back of the oven in eevee, ive tried in cycles and this works but dont want to render in cycles.
Im pretty new to blender but dont know whats going on here. Ive turned on screen space refraction in both render settings and material settings.
[image: I can see the monkey but not the back of the oven??]

[image: ?]

Comment: Please provide blend file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible reasons:

1. Backface is disabled. In this case you can see only one side of the face, the outer one (backface) is hidden.
2. The material of oven is transparent or also marked as refractive. This makes this material excluded from base layer and rendered with glass. So then the opacity applied on top of the base layer, you don't see the object because the base layer is empty.

Here is material settings for oven (Not for the glass). Note that Backface Culling is off, Blend Mode is Opaque, Screen Space Refraction is off:

[image]